# Multiple TCP connection from one client to one Server at the same time

Tags: java, multithreading, tcp

My question is also in the title. For example, I am a client and I am trying to connect One Server at the same time.

Here is the situation

Server Ip : 10.10.10.10
Server Port : 1010

Client has two threads. One of the thread connects with the Server, and keeping connection alive. Always connected. Always receiving dead or alive signal from the server.

Second thread is sending message thread. This thread gets the information from its sibling thread and if connected host alive, sends message.

Im trying to implement this situation in Java with using netty but, message sender thread couldnt establish connection with the host.

Is this problem about my code or tcp protocol?

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is your code. Demonstration: Open a web browser, go to stackoverflow. Open a second web browser, go to stackoverflow. If you do both at the same time, the internet does not explode; they both work.

Comment: But these are different processes, arent they? Threads are in the same process. Does it make a difference?

Comment: The server is unrelated to the client process model.

Answer (score 0):

This is fully supported in tcp, so you should debug the code.

Over long distance internet connections one can even use multiple parallel connections to achieve higher throughput than using a single one.

Comment: Allright then. I ll share my code tomorrow. Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -1):

Could be due to how the server handles connections. If it's single threaded and handles only one connection at a time, that could be the reason. Which means, the server holds on to your first connection from thread1 and while that is still incomplete, it cannot accept another connection (from thread2 in your case). Try handling each connection in a separate thread or multiplexing using java.nio.channels.Selector.

(This could have been a comment. But I dont have the reps.)

Comment: I dont have any access to Server's codes. I don't even have a chance to see the code. But I ll share my code tomorrow as I said. Thanks alot